# GKTurnBasedMatch receive data

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center, gkturnbasedmatch

I am trying to implement a turn-based app, and there is no problem with sending turn data, but I see no way of receiving data automatically. So far, I have found out that much:

- There is a `GKTurnBasedEventHandlerDelegate`-protocol. It is easy to implement, but where do I set that object to be a delegate of whatever it has to be a delegate of? It does not seem to be a delegate of `GKTurnBasedMatch`, or `GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController`, or `GKMatchMaker`.
- There is also a method of `GKTurnBasedMatch` which is called `loadMatchDataWithCompletionhandler`, but, as far as I understand, it is only called once when you kinda have a gut feeling that the match needs to be updated. How am I to know that it has to be updated? Do I have to fire this function every second or so?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I have set `[GKTurnBasedEventHandler sharedTurnBasedEventHandler].delegate` to be a static instance that implements `GKTurnBasedEventHandlerDelegate`. It still never gets called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set it with below statement, it becomes the delegate of a shared instance:

```
[[GKTurnBasedEventHandler sharedTurnBasedEventHandler] setDelegate:self];
```

You do not need to call `loadMatchDataWithCompletionhandler` manually actually, when one of the participants call `endTurnWithMatchData` all other participants will be notified through `GKTurnBasedEventHandler` delegate method:

```
-(void) handleTurnEventForMatch:(GKTurnBasedMatch *)match didBecomeActive:(BOOL)didBecomeActive
```

That's where you need to update UI. Beware that simulator does not support `GKTurnBasedEventHandler`  delegate methods, they only get called in actual devices.

Comment: Actually, I am currently running this on a simulator. It's a pity it doesn't work there.